# Can I remove and re-add AD DS role to activate Server 2012 Standard without losing data or settings

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

As title states, can I temporarily remove the AD DS role on Server 2012 Standard in order to convert (activate) evaluation copy to full licensed copy and then re-add the role and everything should be back up (after re-syncing with DC)?

Comment: Define `everything`.

Comment: Yes sir :) I created a member server for a different site (did this at the DC site to get all working) but users and GPOs have been created on the member server and the two ADs haven't replicated since the initial time. A site-to-site VPN has only just been installed (many months later) so it's these changes I mean.

Comment: Why don't you just change the product key and activate Windows?

Comment: You can't convert an evaluation to a production with a product key if it's got AD DS role. That's why I'm asking if I'll lose anything by "temporarily" removing the role -> activating/converting -> re-add AD DS role -> hope and pray users/groups/GPOs remain intact?

Answer (score 0):

I never got problem activating a server with AD DS ont it. I just did it 5 minutes ago.
If you have problem open a CLI type slui 3 then enter your key. It should activate without problem.

Comment: I've been directed to this previously: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574204.aspx